# SQL : Generate same number till next zero

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table where I have a column as mentioned below :

Table1 :

```
Col1    
1   
0   
0   
1   
0   
1   
1   
1   
0   
0   
1   
1
```

What I want is same ID starting from 1 till next 0.

Result:

```
Table1 :
col1     B
1       ID1
0       ID1
0       ID1
1       ID2
0       ID2
1       ID3
1       ID4
1       ID5
0       ID5
0       ID5
1       ID6
1       ID7
```

Comment: There is no "next" -- SQL table rows are not ordered.

Comment: Next is not defined here. You have no column driving the order of rows. And without it, it is not possible to determine which is next

Answer (score 0):

You can do this  by counting the number of ones before a given value.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So you need a column that specifies the ordering.  With that you can calculate a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*, sum(col) over (order by <ordering col>) as id
from t;
```

I prefer numeric ids, but if you want this as a string:

```
select t.*, concat('id', sum(col) over (order by <ordering col>)) as id
from t;
```